# Wake-On-Lan not working on Ubuntu; works completely out of the box on Windows 10

Tags: wakeup

So my ifconfig currently looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/Gb0K8ek6), with `enp9s0` being my main network interface. I tried doing

```
sudo ethtool enp9s0
```

which gave me [this](https://pastebin.com/rTHEq1w5).

From what I've read, `Supports Wake-on: d` and `Wake-on: d` need to be set to `g`, so I tried doing

```
ethtool -s enp9s0 wol g
```

which gives me:

```
weetile@weetile-DESKTOP:~$ ethtool -s enp9s0 wol g
Cannot get current wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
not setting wol
```

Does anyone know how to get this working? I know my NIC definitely supports it as it works completely fine out of the box under Windows 10. Thanks!

(The network adapter is Killer E2200)

Comment: `$ ethtool -s enp9s0 wol g`  ... sudo ... "I know my NIC definitely supports it as it works completely fine out of the box under Windows 10" Windows aint Linux. And hardware working under Windows doest not mean it is 100% compatible with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The feature was disabled on the driver for these devices. From [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#alx_driver_support):

> For some newer Atheros-based NICs (such as Atheros AR8161 and Killer
>   E2500), WOL support has been disabled in the mainline `alx` module due
>   to a bug causing unintentional wake-up (see [this patch
>   discussion](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg242477.html)). A
>   patch can be applied (or installed as a
>   [dkms](https://wiki.archlinux.org//index.php/Dkms) module)
>   which both restores WOL support and fixes the underlying bug, as
>   outlined in [this
>   thread](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61651).

The kernel bugzilla thread has updated versions of the patch, but doesn't seem to show any activity that might indicate a fix will be merged. 6 years since it was disabled, I don't know if it will ever be enabled upstream. It might be worth it to file a Launchpad bug and hope that Ubuntu devs will apply the patch. (Mine is a Killer E2500, running Arch Linux with kernel 5.4.14-arch1-1, so I don't have that option.)

Answer (score 0):

try this: https://github.com/AMV007/alx_dkms_installer
also don't forget to disable TLP WAKEONLAN: set WOL_DISABLE=N in /etc/default/tlp
all working at my PC now. (killer 2500 card)